# Client-Server Communication with XML

Tags: java, xml, frameworks, client-server, communication

I'm looking for java frameworks, patterns or technics which allow a client server architecture to communicate via xml.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Pick any you like: SOAP, XML-RPC, custom XML-based protocol over TCP (or UDP).

Really, your question is too vague and in need of additional constraints, so community can give you more useful answer.

Comment: A web service approche might be a overhead. Then I would have to transform my xml standard to a wsdl on each side, right? Performance will suffer...

Comment: JAX-RS RESTful Web Services is a light weight framework that operates via XML (and JSON) over the HTTP protocol.  There are serveral implementations of this framework Jersey is the reference implmentation (https://jersey.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant Java EE standards supported by most vendors are:

- [Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311)
- [Java API for RESTFul Web Services (JAX-RS)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224)

I have recently written a series of blog posts explaining how easy this is to do using JAX-RS:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html

Comment: You target relational databases in your blog. In my case, I work with xml, in more details with owl and rdf. The networking between clients and server should be with good performance.

Comment: The data in my example comes from a database.  The interaction between client an server is done through XML via JAX-RS over the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Acctualy RESTful Jersey looks pretty nice! Thanks for the input!!

Comment: I just saw the JBoss-Jetty framework. They also offer a layer for the HTTP protocol. Do you think this works the same way like Jersey?

Comment: I work on the Java EE stack that includes Jersey, so I don't have anything nice to say about JBoss.

Comment: I understand. 
What about RMI. Does Jersey support RMI?

Comment: When you say RMI, do you mean the remote method aspect or the object serialization aspect?

Comment: The remote method aspect. Acctualy I have a more important question: is it possible that the server can send messages to the clients in Jersey? Perhaps this is agains the RESTful idea.

Comment: Jersey/JAX-RS/REST provides a means for clients to access server side data via URIs.  It is not appropriate for pushing data to clients.

Comment: Java Message Service (JMS) may be more appropriate for your use case, refer to:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-142945.html